# Why not 'to effect'?

Tags: differences

> [To give effect to something or to carry/bring/put something into effect is to make it begin doing what it was intended to do.](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/effect#ld_entry_v2_jumplink_effect_2)

Are these verb phrases ('to give effect...', to + verb + into + effect) containing 'effect' prolix and tortuous? Why not simply use 'to effect'? [They](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/23223-Give-effect-to) transpire  to suggest that there may be differences?

Comment: It seems straightforward enough to me that your own first link clearly identifies a common distinction affecting the choice over which form to use. You *give effect to X* when *X* is something that already "exists", but hasn't *yet* been "activated" so it will actually do whatever it's intended to do (such as a plan that hasn't been put into practice yet). Often when you *effect X*, you cause *X* (which didn't previously "exist") to come into being. The idea that all "longer" phrasings are prolix, tortuous or otherwise "undesirable" is a serious misconception.

Comment: Because "to effect" is already a verb that [means something (slightly) different](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effect).

Comment: @jwpat7 Better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *effect* something is produce that something as a result. If you effect a change in your lifestyle or effect a reconciliation between two friends, it is you, the **subject**, who are ‘effective’.

To *give effect to* something or *put it into effect* is to cause that something to become capable of producing effects. If you put a change in your lifestyle into effect you make it capable of producing future changes to your health, productivity, pleasure, and so forth. If you put a reconciliation between two friends into effect you make them capable of future cooperation and mutual intercourse. In these cases it is also, and focally, the **objects** of your action which become ‘effective’.